# Why Strapi bring limit data for relations?

Tags: graphql, strapi

I am using `graphQl` with `Strapi`, I have one `question` table and one `question-option` table, and I write a query to bring data for me by relation. All things working correctly except those questions that have more than 10 options. it just brings 10 options not more.

**My query:**

```
query {
    questions(filters: {for: {contains: "owner"}}) {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          number
          mode
          for
          description
          title
          question_options {
            data {
              id
              attributes {
                option
                score
                status
              }
            }
          }
          style_template {
            ... on ComponentQuestionerImageWithTitleColor {
              imageType
              color
              image {
                data {
                  attributes {
                    url
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

**This is my table:**
[image]

Comment: I have just paginate ``question_options(sort: "id",pagination: { page: 1, pageSize: 100 }) {...}`` and it works correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the default configuration when you're retrieving items, you need to have pagination implemented for more than 10 items as mentioned [**`here`**](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/graphql-api.html#pagination-by-page),

```
documents(pagination: { start: 20, limit: 30 }) {
```